# Pickle ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Tags: python, encoding, binary, pickle

I want to create a very basic Q&A chatbot. Given a list of questions & answers that I use as my dataset, I want to train it in order to return relevant answers, depending on a hard-coded question (different every time). First I tokenize, cleaning up, then using cosine similarity, but it gives me an error, which is (I guess) a pickle issue.

**UPDATED**

```html
import csv
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import Counter
import pickle
import os.path
import re, math

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
stopwords = stopwords.words('english') 

extra_stopwords = stopwords + ['I', 'can']
WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')




def get_clean_data():


    clean_data_set = {
    'questions' : {},
    'answers' : {}
    }

    reader = csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8"))
    tags = []
    counter = 0

    for r in reader:
        question = str(r[0].encode('utf-8'))
        answer = str(r[1].encode('utf-8'))

        _, tags_question = get_tags(question)
        _, tags_answer = get_tags(answer)

        clean_data_set['answers'][answer] = tags_answer + tags_question
        clean_data_set['questions'][question] = text_to_vector(question)

        counter += 1

        # hardcode the number :)
        print (counter, ' out of 746')

    # pickle.dump(clean_data_set, open('dump.dict', 'wb'))
    with open('dump.dict', 'wb') as my_dump_file:
        pickle.dump(clean_data_set, my_dump_file)


def get_tags(text, use_set = True):
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    # remove stop words from tokens
    # make it lower case
    filtered_words = [word.lower() for word in tokens if word not in extra_stopwords]

    # return non duplicate values by default
    if use_set == True:
        filterd_words = list(set(filtered_words))

    return Counter(filtered_words), filtered_words

# simple cosine similarity measure
def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
     intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
     numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

     sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
     sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
     denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

     if not denominator:
        return 0.0
     else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator

def text_to_vector(text):
     words = WORD.findall(text)
     return Counter(words)


# question_set is the data we had
def get_cosine_value(question, question_set):

    question_vector = text_to_vector(question)

    cosine = get_cosine(question_vector, question_set)

    return cosine    



def answer_question(question, top = 5):
    with open('dump.dict', 'rb') as my_dump_file:
        data_set = pickle.load(my_dump_file)
    # data_set = pickle.load(open('dump.dict', 'rb'))
        pickle.dump(a, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


    _, question_tags = get_tags(question)

    ranking_dict = {}
    similar_questions_rank = {}
    for entry in data_set['answers']:
        tags = data_set['answers'][entry]
        # rank is the intersection between the list of tags from the question
        # and the list of tags associated to answers
        rank = len(set(question_tags).intersection(tags))
        ranking_dict[entry] = rank

    for entry in data_set['questions']:
        cosine_similarity = get_cosine_value(question, data_set['questions'][entry])
        similar_questions_rank[entry] = cosine_similarity

    sorted_similarity_dict = sorted(similar_questions_rank.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    sorted_ranking_dict = sorted(ranking_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # sort them by rank
    for item in sorted_ranking_dict[0:top-1]:
        print ('Rank: ', item[1])
        print ('Answer: ', item[0])
        print ('\n\n')

    # sort them by rank
    for item in sorted_similarity_dict[0:top-1]:
        print ('Rank: ', item[1])
        print ('Question: ', item[0])

#get_clean_data()


question = 'why all these errors?'

answer_question(question)
```

This is the **updated** error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joasa\Desktop\si\main.py", line 133, in <module>
answer_question(question)
  File "C:\Users\joasa\Desktop\si\main.py", line 94, in answer_question
data_set = pickle.load(my_dump_file)
EOFError: Ran out of input
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

Can someone help please? I have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: `ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument` This error is very straightforward. Change `open('dump.dict', 'rb', encoding='utf-8')` to `open('dump.dict', 'rb')`

Comment: Nope, it was like that in the first place and it was giving me this error: `EOFError: Ran out of input`

Comment: What lead you to believe that changing the encoding has anything to do with your original error? Remove the `encoding` argument and update your question with the actual error so you can get a solution for your actual problem and not your attempted solution (XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: So, just because I added `encoding='utf-8` to see if something would change, is the reason you are downvoting my question, instead of providing some actual help?

Comment: Where does it say that I'm the one who downvoted?

Comment: I'm sorry, i thought you did it. My apologies. It is updated now

Comment: @OP Have you tried using `'wb'` (binary write mode) in your `open` when you do the pickle dump in your `get_clean_data` function ?

Comment: Yes, but I still get the same EOFError

Answer (score 1):

I think it comes from this line in your `get_clean_data` function:

```
pickle.dump(clean_data_set, open('dump.dict', 'w'))
```

See here you open the file for writing, but you never close it, so when you try to read it there is nothing to signify that the end of file has been reached. To avoid stuff like this from happening, use a context manager block:

```
with open('dump.dict', 'wb') as my_dump_file:
    pickle.dump(clean_data_set, my_dump_file)
```

That way, whichever way you exit the `with` block, you are guaranteed to close your file.

You should also do the same when loading your pickle dump in `answer_question`:

```
with open('dump.dict', 'rb') as my_dump_file:
    data_set = pickle.load(my_dump_file)
```

Comment: It didn't work. I updated the question, so that you see the error after your suggestion

Comment: @OP same thing applies when you load the dump, use another context manager. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Can you check my updated question? I still get eoferror :/

Comment: Have you checked that `dump.dict` contains *some* data ? Is the file physically present where you expect it to be ? Maybe you should give a literal path to this file.

Comment: Also I would definitely initialize `clean_data_set` dictionnary *within* `get_clean_data_set` function, unless you absolutely need it declared as a global variable.

Comment: It is now initialized within the get_clean_data_function, if this is what you meant. Also, the dump.dict file is present, but is 0 kb.. so maybe it is empty, but what do you mean giving a literal path to this file?

Comment: I mean specify something like `"C:\Users\joasa\Desktop\si\dump.dict"`, as to give him a path where you are *sure* to have sufficient privileges for writing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146776/discussion-between-valentin-b-and-joasa).